# Angular JS http.post

Tags: angularjs

I will send some data to server using http.post like this;

```
test.controller("MyController2", function ($scope, $http) {    

        var array = [];

        $scope.postdata = function (name, age, adress) {
            var dataSend = { name: name, age: age, adress: adress };                

            try {
                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "wfrmPostData.aspx/SendJsonData",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataSend),
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                }).then
                (
                    function success(response) {                                                      
                        array.push(response.data.d);
                        $scope.showData2 = array;                           
                    },
                    function error(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.showData = status;
                    }
                );
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        };
    });
```

server side code is here:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SendJsonData(string name, string age, string adress)
    {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
               { "name", name },
               { "age", age },
               { "adress", adress }
           };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = js.Serialize(keyValues);
        return json;
    }
```

`myShowData2` variable is not working in ng-repeat tag.

response.data.d getting like this: `{"name":"asd","age":"2","adress":"asd"}`

Html code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="record2 in showData2">
                <td> {{ record2.name }} </td>
                <td> {{ record2.age }} </td>
                <td> {{ record2.adress }} </td>

            </tr>
```

How can I do this.Thanks

Comment: just use {{ name}} {{age}}

Comment: Hi Praven, Itried your solution. This solution work but slightly lacking. my variable array hold to many json variable, like                                              { "name": "Asd", "age": "1", "adress": "Asd"},
{ "name": "Dsa", "age": "2", "adress": "Dsa"},   in your solution, table show two same records (like{ "name": "Dsa", "age": "2", "adress": "Dsa"}). I want to do add record in server side then show all record in table

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is this line:

```
$scope.showData2 = array.push(response.data.d);
```

`array.push` returns the length of the array. Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example). You can do:

```
array.push(response.data.d);  

$scope.showData2 = array;
```

Comment: Hi Frank I do your answer but, in table not show some data

Comment: Is `response.data.d` an array? If so just assign that to `$scope.showData2`.

Comment: response.data.d getting like this : {"name":"asd","age":"2","adress":"asd"}

Comment: Frank, I add success func like: var personeller = [
                                { "name": "asd", "age": "2", "adress": "dsa" }
                            ];
                            $scope.showData = personeller; this code working fine in ng-repeat

Comment: Hmm seems like that should work then. Maybe you can show a live example.

Comment: Your question mentions `myShowData2`. Are you accidentally using the wrong variable name in the real code?

Comment: I use right variable in the real code. I think, my response.data.d must be        var personeller = [ { "name": "asd", "age": "2", "adress": "dsa" } ]; format.

Comment: Ok, it seems like `$scope.showData2 = array` should still work though. In both cases you are assigning a new array to `$scope.showData2`. Weird.

Comment: $scope.showData output is : [{"name":"dsa","age":"1","adress":"wer"}], $scope.showData2 output is : ["{\"name\":\"asd\",\"age\":\"2\",\"adress\":\"asd\"}"] if I can delete '\' or formatted like showData,  showData2 will working fine.

Comment: It may be a problem with the serialization happening on the server. Perhaps it is being serialized twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning showData2 to array variable , you are just pushing it into array varaible , rather you can use as below

```
 $scope.showData2=[];
$scope.showData2.push(response.data.d);
```

in success callback , hope this works